# Unexpected non-void return value in void function Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

```
public func connectAPI(method:String, query: String){
    Alamofire.request("http://\(linkSite)/api.php?method=\(method)&\(query)").responseJSON { response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            return JSON//Unexpected non-void return value in void function
        }
    }

}
```

Ошибкa `Unexpected non-void return value in void function`. Что делать?

Comment: Как что? не пытаться что-то возвращать из функции с типом возврата void. Или изменить тип возврата на JSON (или какого там типа response.result.value).

Comment: @Akina, Нельзя делать возврат из assync функций. Нужно делать closure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменить

```
public func connectAPI(method:String, query: String, success: @escaping (NSDictionary) -> Void, failed: @escaping()->Void){
        Alamofire.request("http://\(linkSite)/api.php?method=\(method)&\(query)").responseJSON { response in
            if let JSON = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {
                success(JSON)
            } else {
                failed()
            }
        }
    }
```

Использовать

```
connectAPI(method: "SOME_METHOD", query: "SOME_QUERY", success: { (JSON) in
            //здесь будет твой JSON как NSDisctionary
        }, failed: {
            //код здесь будет выполняться если запрос провалится
        })
```

Comment: Спасибо, брат, выручил